# Python - Tkinter button size changes when chaging the size of its font

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the fontsize in a Tkinter button. But the button size changes along with it.
I even tried to limit the height and width of the button but nothing seems to work,
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(False, False)
button = Button(root, text="Ihsan", bg="Black", fg="white",
                activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", width=15, height=3,
                font=("ariel", "43"))
button.place(x=350, y=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I get a window with a huge button. Please help

Comment: What size do you want it to be? Are you trying to create a button that is too small for the text to be visible?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to enlarge the text in the button without the button's size increasing.

Comment: Since you used `place()`, you can specify the size in pixel in it: `button.place(x=350, y=20, width=200, height=50)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Width and height of the button in letters (if displaying text) or pixels (if displaying an image).

Here's one way to go, by using size of image to limit size of button when font size changed. Not sure if it is best one.

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def new_font():
    global setting
    setting = 1 - setting
    font = f"ariel {32 if setting else 16}"
    button.configure(font=font)

setting = 0

root = tk.Tk()

im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

root.geometry("300x300")
root.resizable(False, False)
button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text="Ihsan",
    bg="Black",
    fg="white",
    activeforeground="white",
    activebackground="grey",
    width=200,
    height=200,
    font=("ariel", "16"),
    image=photo,
    compound='center')

button.place(x=30, y=20)
size = tk.Button(root, text="Size", command=new_font)
size.place(x=30, y=250)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an image

Comment: @ihsan: you can create an invisible 1x1 pixel image along with the text. The use of the pixel will cause the widget to be sized in pixels rather than characters.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height is what is giving you the large button. Height in this case means 3 fontsize high.
Default is that it only enclose the text.

Margins you provide with *pad*, either in the widget itself, or when you pack it.
Using *place* is a bit uncommon and has its specific usecases, it does not look like you need it. The *pack* geometry manager can be used instead.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(False, False)
button = Button(root, text="Ihsan", bg="Black", fg="white",
                activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey",# width=15, height=3,
                font=("ariel", "43"))
#button.place(x=350, y=20)
button.pack(side=RIGHT)
root.mainloop()
```